# Why a different type variable can be used as an argument of a parameter of const reference parameter in C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

```
void foo(const int& v) {
    int x = v;
    std::cout << x;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned y = 1;
    foo(y);
}
```

Is passing `y` in place of a `const int&` legal in C++

Comment: Don't use code snippet for something other than html/css/javascript.

Answer (score 8):

There are two factors that allow your code to work. First, function arguments are allowed up to one implicit conversion if it would allow them to match an overload. Second, `const` references can bind to temporaries. What is happening here is `y` is implicitly converted to `int`, creating a temporary copy. `v` is then bound to that temporary.

Consider the following example :

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(const unsigned int & v) {
    std::cout << &v << '\n';
}

void bar(const int & v) {
    std::cout << &v << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int y = 1;
    std::cout << &y << '\n';
    foo(y);
    bar(y);
    return 0;
}
```

You will find that `foo(y)` prints the same address as `y` where as `bar(y)` prints a different address. This won't work with non-`const` references. Notably, if you could, it would mean that changing `v` might not actually change `y`.

Comment: I think in this case, the implicit conversion does more harm than good.  I wonder why the language is designed to allow this?

Comment: @xiaofengz Most implicit conversions are inherited from the early days of c. Most developers I've talked about it with share my opinion that we would be better off without them, but they're kept around for compatibility. c++ has removed some of the more dangerous conversions, such as void* to other pointer types and string literals to `char*`. Strongly type enum are another example of c++ distancing itself from the implicit conversions of c where it can.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this this can be quite annoying. Compilation passes due to an implicit conversion of `y` to an anonymous temporary `int` at the calling site, and a `const int&` binding is allowed.

You can defeat this by writing

```
void foo(unsigned v) = delete;
```

or even

```
template<typename Y> void foo(Y v) = delete;
```

so *all* overloads other than the one you have explicitly given are deleted.

Comment: If I want to rely on the compiler to match the type, I would have to 'delete' all possible conversions.  Doesn't feel like a viable solution.

Comment: @xiaofengz: We've addressed that: use a template.